# How to run async function after widget is completely build in Flutter (long period function)

Tags: flutter, user-interface, asynchronous, widget

I have function that reads BLE characteristics data (numers in List type). I want to run it asynchronously after widget is built. **I need access to context variable (Because of Provider - state management library)**. Data gathered from device are coming in long period of time (tens of minutes, usually 20-30 minutes). I want to fill List with this data, but need this, before described, functionality of this async function. How can I do that? Data will asyncchronously be read and will be "coming" to UI (will be presented in a ListView, which I already have). I am using latest Flutter.

Currently I read data by clicking ElevatedButton (onPressed), but I need before mentioned async functions working in a loop.

```
      onPressed: () async =>
                {
                result = await  inter.readCharacteristic(characteristic),
                print(new String.fromCharCodes(result)),
                },
```

I need to check BLE characteristics every 10 sec.

**Where should I place such function?**

Comment: I suggest you attach the whole code, it is hard to find the root cause with just a little of snippet code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any state management library ?

If so then you can start your async function at the start of your build method by doing something like `Future(() { myAsyncfunc(); });`, update state in that func and use state management library to trigger widget re-build. Although I am sure you can come up with a better logic to handle this.

If no, then you can try passing buildContext and setState to that async function and call setState from that func. Make sure to check for context.mounted before calling setState.

Comment: Yes I use Provider, that's why I need context variable to get info about some configuration settings.

Comment: As I mentioned I need context for: var inter = Provider.of<BleDeviceInteractor>(context, listen: true);